# Issue with the browser link on my ASP.NET 3 Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, browser-link

I have an issue with the browser link on my ASP.NET 3 Core MVC project (i'm a begginer).
When I press Ctrl + Alt + Enter, I always get a window asking "Do you want to stop debugging?"
Yes -> Stops debugging, doesn't update browser.
Non -> Doesn't update browser.
Do you know what could cause that ?

Comment: So, if I understand corectly: you start debugging a project and when it shows in your browser you hit ctrl+alt+enter? If so, what do you expect to achieve with this shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you'd like to do html/css testing work on MVC razor view(s) using [Browser Link feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-5.0), and you start the project with debugging mode (**F5**), which cause the following warning once you click the Browser Link refresh button.

[image]

Please try to start the project without debugging (**CTL+F5**), then click the Browser Link refresh button to make the connected browser(s) automatically refresh.